# LWC lightning-formatted-number doesn't work

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have lightning-formatted-number with currency type and if value has more than 15 digits then it doesn't work (left is work, right not):

[image]

I show it with a wired method and I have 100 fields, so I don't want to have 100 getters. Is there a way to avoid this without getter?

Answer (score 0):

Are all of those digit significant? If not, can you modify the values when generated?  You mentioned "a wired method"; if the values are being computed in Apex, you can use `Decimal.setScale()`.  Like `Decimal.round()`, it supports eight different rounding models, but unlike `round()` it allows you to round to a specified number of decimal places.

The method returns a new Decimal, so you'll need to apply it to your calculated value and store the result.  Here's an example pulled from one of my projects:

```
this.tx.Local_Amount__c = (Math.abs(writeoff.Local_Amount__c) * guarantor.Guarantee_Percentage__c / 100.0).setScale(2, LoanUtil.RoundingMode);
```

In this case, `LoanUtil.RoundingMode` is a centralized constant to allow all rounding code in the system to use the same value, which can be changed if needed. In practice, we only ever use `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`, as this is the most common for financial transactions.  If you expect lots of values ending in '999...' which you don't want rounded up, consider `RoundingMode.FLOOR`.